# How to get the slingshot effect (elastic band) with trajectory prediction based on the pull and angle in 3d world

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first, im unable to create a elastic bad over my model (slingshot), is there any unity component (like cloth), that I can use that will give me the elastic band effect while the user pulls to launch a ball.

Second, how to create a trajectory based on the elastic stretch and the angle of launch.

Im able to do the math to launch a ball based on the amount of stretch and the angle of release, but is there a simple way to create elastic band (I am not a designer so I dont know how to create a model with a band and animate it in the gameplay).

public class SlingShot : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject launcher;

private bool isAiming;
private float sphereRadius;

public GameObject prefabBall;
public GameObject activeBall;
public float speedMultiplier = 16f;

void Start()
{
    isAiming = false;
    sphereRadius = this.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius;
    activeBall = null;
}

private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    launcher.SetActive(true);
}

private void OnMouseExit()
{
    launcher.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input. GetMouseButton(0) && !isAiming)
    {
        isAiming = true;
        activeBall = Instantiate(prefabBall) as GameObject;
        activeBall.transform.position = launcher.transform.position;
        activeBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    }
    else if (isAiming && (check if the mouse is released))
    {
        Vector3 mousePositionScreen = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePositionScreen.z = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
        Vector3 mousePositionWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePositionScreen);
        Vector3 dragVector = mousePositionWorld - launcher.transform.position;

        if (dragVector.magnitude > sphereRadius)
        {
            dragVector.Normalize();
            dragVector *= sphereRadius;
        }

        activeBall.transform.position = launcher.transform.position + dragVector;

        if (isAiming)
        {
            isAiming = false;
            Rigidbody rb = activeBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            rb.velocity = -dragVector * speedMultiplier;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The above code helped me launch the ball but, im stuck how to create elastic band material that stretches with the pull and also the trajectory prediction of the ball based on the pull and angle

Comment: There is no pre-built component that does this. You're going to have to write it yourself.

Comment: @Draco18s I understand that, but instead of creating the Elastic Bone using 3d modeling, is there alternate way to do that in unity? like using a cloth? im not that good with unity just trying to learn and build as i go, so whats the best way to get a full length slingshot effect ?

Comment: There are 2 major questions in this post - the elastic band and the trajectory prediction. Asking both makes this post too broad - one of them should be removed. It can then be asked in a separate post.

Comment: *`like using a cloth?`* See my earlier comment: *`There is no pre-built component that does this.`* Cloth is a pre-built component. There is no pre-built component that does what you want.